# Set up multiple templates on one store

Tags: theme

I have one domain with one store and store views for each language.

I would like to set up an over branding system on the site but without duplicating all the products.

Is there a way to set up several themes on each store view so that based on cookie information, the appropriate theme can be selected by Magento.

If this is possible I would also like some advise as to the maximum number of themes that could be applied if you have experience regarding this.

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to set different theme by each store right in the backend if you select your specific store view and make your setting under the design tab different to the default. There is no limitation to the number of themes.

Comment: I'm looking to set multiple themes per "store view". As far as I can see from the admin you can set a master theme and device/browser specific themes, but this must be possible programmatically. If a user comes from a link I want to set a cookie and show the theme based on that cookie, therefore creating white label sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can either move your store views onto store group level to free up one level of the fallback or observe some event that triggers early enough but after config has already been loaded and replace the `design/theme/default` node.